# Running bash script modes

Tags: linux, bash

What is the difference between running:

```
:~$./myscript

:~$bash ./myscript

:~$bash -c "./myscript"
```

(assuming `./myscript` is exec'able)?

Comment: Nothing much except the second one won't honor the shebang line

Answer (score 2):

`./myscript` runs `myscript` with whatever interpreter is specified in the shebang. `myscript` needs to have the executable bit set.

`bash ./myscript` runs `myscript` with bash. `myscript` doesn't need to be executable, and since bash is given a file to run, it is not even looking for it in the PATH, so `bash myscript` will work just as well.

`bash -c "./myscript"` starts a bash instance to execute a command, which happens to make it execute `./myscript` with whatever interpreter is specified in the shebang (so it is similar to the first case, with an added bash process). The argument to `bash -c` is any bash command or sequence of commands (try `bash -c "echo 'aa';echo 'bb'"`).

And you haven't mentioned `. ./myscript`

Comment: or `exec ./myscript` which is replacing the current shell with the script.

Comment: @xenoid What do You mean by "added bash process"?

Comment: In the first case the bash interpreter that runs `myscript` is a direct child of your shell. In the third case the direct child of your shell is the `bash` command that you invoke, and it will itself spawn another bash instance to run `myscript`.

Comment: @So what w'd be the advantage of using all this 3 solutions?

Comment: No good reason to use the third AFAIK. The second would be used either to override the shebang or because there is no shebang yet. The first one is the canonical one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myscript` is executable and is having a shebang line pointing to the `bash` binary - there is no difference between running `./myscript` alone or `bash ./myscript`, but running `bash -c ./myscript` is creating one more subshell level - which you can see by checking the `SHLVL` var (`bash terminal > running bash -c > running shebang line with bash` 3 x bash )

Usually you're in a bash terminal session, when executing `./myscript` the shebang line is calling `bash` and creating a `bash subshell` in which it's running the commands.

```
30311 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 8419 pts/0    S+     0:00  \_ /bin/bash ./test.sh
 8420 pts/0    R+     0:00      \_ ps f
SHELL LEVEL: 2  # is 3 when running with bash -c
8419  # that's the $BASHPID
```

Take this code below (test.sh) and try it yourself.

```
#!/bin/bash

ps f
echo "SHELL LEVEL: $SHLVL"
echo $BASHPID
```

Comment: There will be a difference if the shebang points to another shell (zsh, or even /bin/sh which may not be bash in some cases)

Comment: The question is tagged with `linux` and `bash` that leads to the assumption that the script is a `bash` script running in a `bash` environment.

Comment: It's about the bash command, yes, but assuming the script is meant for bash is a mistake often made in practice. Many scripts in products for servers are written for ksh, which is considered more unix-agnostic (Solaris, AIX, BSD family...).

Comment: Yes, it could be a python script as well.